# Setting up a probability tree

Tags: probability

Hi I need some help setting up a probability tree. Here is the questions

> The internal audit group of Suburban Civic Bank has found that 10% of
>   all personal loans are in default. Homeowners represent 20% of the
>   loans in default and 70% of the loans that are not in default.

Now from what I understand there the two major categories of loans are personal and non-personal, Which are sub divided into default loans and non default loans. However, if this is the case I dont know where the *Home Owner* category fits in since I think this is a question with only four nodes (four categories). Unless non-personal loans are equal to *Home Owners*. However, this is also not correct since the percentage of *Home owners* defaulting and not defaulting does not add up to hundred.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you can do much with these data, but at least you can calculate the probability of home owners.

Let's put `D`= *default*, `~D`= *not default*, `Pers` = *personal*, `H` = *home owners* and `p = P(Pers)`. We have

1. `P(D & Pers) = 0.1 p`
2. `P(H) = 0.2 P(D)`
3. `P(H) = 0.7 P(~D) = 0.7 (1 - P(D))`

Thus,

```
0.2 P(D) = P(H) = 0.7 - 0.7 P(D)
0.9 P(D) = 0.7
P(D) = 7/9.
```

Hence,

```
P(H) = 0.2 7/9 = 1.4/9
```

Note however that I've not used the eq. in item 1 above because I don't see any way to deduce something from it.